# Divide pandas multiindex slices by each other

Tags: pandas, slice, multi-index

I have a pandas multiindex data frame with four index levels. I am trying to divide a slice of this dataframe by another slice of the same dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={"data_provider": ["prov_a", "prov_a", "prov_a", "prov_a", "prov_a", "prov_a"],
          "indicator": ["ind_a", "ind_a", "ind_a", "ind_b", "ind_b", "ind_b"],
          "unit": ["EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR"],
          "year": ["2017", "2018","2019", "2017","2018","2019"],
          "country1": [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6],
          "country2": [4, 5, 6, 40, 50, 60]}
)

df = df.set_index(["data_provider", "indicator", "unit", "year"], drop=True)

print(df.loc[(slice(None), ["ind_a"]), :] / df.loc[(slice(None), ["ind_b"]), :])
```

Although the individual slices produce a valid slice of `df`, this simple division leads to all NaN. If I were to drop the first index level and perform the same slicing and division operation, I do get correct results. However, the `indicator` index-level will then be removed, which makes sense.

```
df1.droplevel(0)
print(df.loc["ind_a", :] / df.loc["ind_b", :])
```

At the end of the day, I would like to append the result of the division to the existing `df` dataframe. I need to assign the first two levels of the multiindex. Something like `data_provider="prov_a"` and `indicator="ind_c"`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source of your problem is that both sides of division have first values
at level 1 of the MultiIndex.

So if you drop this level of the index and then perform the division:

```
res = df.loc[(slice(None), ["ind_a"]), :].droplevel([1]) / \
    df.loc[(slice(None), ["ind_b"]), :].droplevel([1])
```

you will get the proper result.

To append this result to the source DataFrame, run:

```
res2 = pd.concat([res], keys=['ind_c'], names=['indicator']).swaplevel(0,1)
df = pd.concat([df, res2])
```

The result is:

```
                                   country1  country2
data_provider indicator unit year                    
prov_a        ind_a     EUR  2017       1.0       4.0
                             2018       2.0       5.0
                             2019       3.0       6.0
              ind_b     EUR  2017       2.0      40.0
                             2018       4.0      50.0
                             2019       6.0      60.0
              ind_c     EUR  2017       0.5       0.1
                             2018       0.5       0.1
                             2019       0.5       0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `pd.IndexSlice` and `to_numpy` to strip indexes from divisor so, pandas doesn't enforce data alignment to divde same shaped parts of the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={"data_provider": ["prov_a", "prov_a", "prov_a", "prov_a", "prov_a", "prov_a"],
          "indicator": ["ind_a", "ind_a", "ind_a", "ind_b", "ind_b", "ind_b"],
          "unit": ["EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR"],
          "year": ["2017", "2018","2019", "2017","2018","2019"],
          "country1": [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6],
          "country2": [4, 5, 6, 40, 50, 60]}
)
df = df.set_index(["data_provider", "indicator", "unit", "year"], drop=True)

indx = pd.IndexSlice
df_new = (df.loc[indx[:, 'ind_a'], :].div(df.loc[indx[:, 'ind_b'], :].to_numpy())
            .rename(index={'ind_a':'ind_c'}))
df_out = pd.concat([df,df_new])
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
                                   country1  country2
data_provider indicator unit year                    
prov_a        ind_a     EUR  2017       1.0       4.0
                             2018       2.0       5.0
                             2019       3.0       6.0
              ind_b     EUR  2017       2.0      40.0
                             2018       4.0      50.0
                             2019       6.0      60.0
              ind_c     EUR  2017       0.5       0.1
                             2018       0.5       0.1
                             2019       0.5       0.1
```